# A first-order non-linear ordinary differential equation containing various squares

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

**The Equation:**

Find all differentiable functions $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies:

$$\big(\,f(x)-x\,f'(x)\big)^2 = \big(\,f'(x)\big)^2 + 1 \; \; \; \; \; \text{for all}\,\,\, x \in I,$$
where $I$ is an open interval.

This is not an assignment. And, thanks in advance!

Comment: [f(x)-x f'(x)] look like the numerator of the derivative of [x / f(x)]. May be, this could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two sets of solutions are obtained as shown below :
[image]

Comment: The derivation of the first order ODE leads to a second order ODE. The set of solutions of the second order ODE includes the solutions of the first order ODE, but more solutions which are not solutions of the first order ODE. That is why the functions obtained must be put back into the first order ODE. Those which are not convenient are rejected.

Comment: Nice! Great idea.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if my approach is correct, but I found that:

$$f(x) = A \, x \pm \sqrt{1+A^2}, \quad A \in \mathbb{R},$$

is a solution of your ODE. I used Lagrange-Charpit method in order to solve a "false" 1st order PDE for $f = f(x,y)$, assuming that there's no dependence on $y$.

If you want some more details, just ask for it.

---

**Edit**

The Lagrange-Charpit equations state that, for a non-linear partial differential equation written in the form:

$$G(f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N),p_i,x_i) = 0,$$

where $f$ is an unknown function (dependent variable), $p_i = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$, or in the special case of $N = 2$, $x_i = (x,y) $, in order to simplify the notation, the following relations hold:

$$ \frac{dx}{G_p} = \frac{dy}{G_q} = \frac{df}{pG_p + qG_q} = - \frac{dp}{G_x + pG_f} = -\frac{dq}{G_y + q G_f}, $$

Since:

$$\begin{align}
G & = (f-xp)^2 -p^2-1 = 0,  \\
G_x & = 2(f-xp)(-p),  \\
G_y & = 0,  \\
G_f & = 2 (f-xp),  \\
G_p & =  2 (f-xp)(-x)-2p,  \\
G_q & = 0,
\end{align}
$$ you have:

$$\frac{dx}{2(f-xp)(-x)-2p} = \frac{dy}{0} = \frac{df}{2p(f-xp)(-x)-2p^2} =$$ $$= \frac{dp}{2(f-xp)(-p)+2p(f-xp) } = \frac{dp}{0} = \frac{dq}{2q(f-xp)}.$$

This tells you, among other things, that $dp = 0$, so $p = A$ is a constant. Since $p = f_x$ you can integrate in order to achieve $f$, so:

$$f(x,y) = A x + B(y),$$

for $B(y)$ some arbitrary function of $y$. Substitute back into the original equation, $G = 0$ in order to obtain a relation between $A$ and $B$, which results to be:

$$B^2(y) - A^2 - 1 = 0,$$

so $$B(y) = B = \pm \sqrt{1+A^2},$$ and $B$ does not depend on $y$, as it was expected because $f$ did not depend on $y$ originally.

So in resume, I have treated your original ODE as a first order non-linear PDE for the dependent variable $f = f(x,y)$, but, as we already knew, $f = f(x)$, as it has been shown.

Cheers!

Comment: I'm not familiar with that method, so please give me some (or a lot) more details, at least for this particular ODE. By the way, I'm not sure about whether you mean that the given family of solution is the only one.


P.S: I don't really understand the method by reading the Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics

Comment: Give me some minutes and I will explain myself some more by editing my comment.

Comment: I've just edited some of your minor typos. While doing it, I've realized that $G_p$ must be $2(f-xp)(-x)-2p$. However, all of those don't change your solution, which I'm considering. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: FIY and to sum up, I edited everything about $G_p$ and minor typos as "$G_f = 2(f-xp)$" and "$\frac{df}{pG_p+qG_q}$". Back to your solution, I think firstly we have to reconsider the general method in the case of one of the denominators being zero. Assume that the method includes the case, I think the conclusion (for the case) will probably be that all of the denominators are zero, instead of the respective numerators being zero. (to be continued)

Comment: (continued) If we use your supposed conclusion, beside the consequence of $dp = 0$, we'll have $dy = 0 \Rightarrow y = C$ (?). Also, we'll miss the solution mentioned below. On the other hand, applying my supposed conclusion to your solution, we'll eventually find out that the solution of the initial ODE is $\sqrt{1-x^2}$. However, this still causes a problem of missing solutions, this time is your (linear) family of solution.

Comment: But this function$$f(x) = A \, x \pm \sqrt{1+A^2}, \quad A \in \mathbb{R},$$ does not satisfy the equation!

Comment: Dmoreno: I've just find out other minor typos of yours: you missed some minus signs in front of $dp, dq$.
Smyrlis: Are you sure? "$(Ax \pm \sqrt{1+A^2} - Ax)^2 = (A)^2 + 1$"?

Comment: Thank you Vincent for pointing out and correcting my mistakes. I apologize for any inconvenience (I'm Spanish and when I was writing this it was too late in the evening...). On the other hand, you cannot suppose that if one of the denominator becomes zero then everyone else is too. The characteristic method (and Lagrange-Charpit equations) are all equaled to some $d\lambda$ (see the wikipedia url you posted) which yields to things like $dp = (\ldots) d\lambda$, so when $\ldots$ eventually come to zero, then it must hold $dp = 0$ (and also for the other equations where this happen but...

Comment: ... not for everyone of them). Anyway, what relations have you used to come up whith the $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ solution? I have checked it satisfiest the original ODE but I cannot find what relations you have used. Cheers!

Comment: It's $\sqrt{1-x^2}$. And about the relation (yes, there is a relation, so the function is a true solution), can I reveal it later? (I'll definitely reveal it). Thank you for making it clear about the method, but we still have problems - I think we need to focus on these first. Sorry for inconvenience.